# strange exception in ASP.NET web service when running on IIS

Tags: asp.net, .net, web-services, iis, vb6

Got some strange problem.
I'm developing some complicated Web Services network that uses some VB6 .dll. In my previous post I got some problems with the dll but we've solved them.

So, the new problem is:
When I debug my service (those which uses VB6 dll) on development server from visual studio - everything works fine, the problem starts when I publish my service on IIS (I tried my local IIS). After that, when I call .dll method (as I understand I need to call it by reference - and that's what the compiler tells me) I got an exception:

> *"System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800A000D): Type mismatch      at ..."*

Actually is happens here in the third line:

```
Object s = (Object)OrderId;
Object s1 = (Object)lines.Length;
proxy.OrderRead(ref s, ref s1);
```

OrderId and Legth are integers.

As I understant this is exception that comes from the .dll from vb6 :/

What the problem may be? Why it runs when debugging but fails on IIS?

Answer (score 0):

When debugging in vb6,the IDE will register the dll for you. After publishing, have you may ahve to register your vb6 dll on the server. Open a command prompt and change to the location of the dll and run `regsvr32 myvb6.dll`.

Also, check these settings.
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/281630